# Setting a radial gradient as the background color of a circle on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, gradient, geometry, android-drawable

I draw some circles on a canvas using .drawCircle.

I would like the fill color of that circle to be a radial gradient (or linear gradient if that's not possible).

Basically I want the circles to have some depth to them.

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.

I know I can define a gradient as a drawable, but is there a way to set that as the background for the drawn circle?

For example in WPF I can simply define a LinearGradientBrush and define it's stop points.

Some code for context:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

canvas.drawCircle((float) temp_dot.get_x(),
            (float) temp_dot.get_y(),
            (float) temp_dot.get_radius(),
            paint);
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before drawing the circle, use the following code :

```
paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(
  centerX,
  centerY,
  radius,
  centerColor,
  externalColor,
  Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
 ));
canvas.drawCircle(..., paint);
```

See the [RadialGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html) if you want to have a more custom radial gradient.